# How can we pass cluster id to bootstrap custom action

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I am creating EMR cluster from terraform and calling custom script as a bootstrap action, and my custom script needs newly created cluster ID. I see there is option to pass argument to custom action but it seems not working for me.
I am passing cluster id like `Cluster.Id`
When I checked it in log it is not getting the value of it.

> startExec '/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/Updated_bootstrap_unix.sh Cluster.Id'

Does anyone has Idea how to do this?

```
        provider "aws" {
     access_key="${var.aws_access_key}"
     secret_key="${var.aws_secret_key}"
     region="${var.region}"
                    }

    resource "aws_emr_cluster" "cluster" {
      name          = "${var.environment}-emr"
      release_label = "emr-5.27.0"
      applications  = ["Hadoop"]

      additional_info = <<EOF
    {
      "instanceAwsClientConfiguration": {
        "proxyPort": 8099,
        "proxyHost": "myproxy.example.com"
      }
    }
    EOF

      termination_protection            = false
      keep_job_flow_alive_when_no_steps = true

       ec2_attributes {
        subnet_id                         = "${var.sub_net_id}"
        emr_managed_master_security_group ="${var.master_security_group}"
        emr_managed_slave_security_group  = "${var.slave_security_group}"
        instance_profile                  = "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"
        key_name                          = "${var.keypair}"
      }

      master_instance_group {
        instance_type = "m4.large"
        instance_count = 3
      }

      bootstrap_action {
        path = "${var.bootstrap_action_script}"
        name = "createfolder"
        args = ["instance.isMaster=false","clusterid=instance.Id"]
      }

      core_instance_group {
        instance_type  = "c4.large"
        instance_count = 3

        ebs_config {
          size                 = "10"
          type                 = "gp2"
          volumes_per_instance = 1
        }


      }

      ebs_root_volume_size = 10

      tags = {
        role = "rolename"
        env  = "dev"
      }




      service_role = "EMR_DefaultRole"
    }
```

Sample Custom action script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

      whoami
     sudo su


    echo "I got the cluster id "$1
     clusterid=$1
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant Terraform and script. Also, what Terraform and provider versions?

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: terraform version Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v2.32.0

Comment: The id is created after the cluster deployed but the bootstrap is submitted with the cluster deployment, so in this way, you cannot submit the id. You may try to obtain yhe id from the emr metadata by curl to 169.254.169.254 somewhere I cant remember.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Lamanus.
I am able to get it inside my bootstrap script using below command.
clusterid=$(cat /mnt/var/lib/info/extraInstanceData.json | grep jobFlowId  | awk -F\" '{print $4}')